# Frequently Index replication is failing

Tags: solr, lucene, solrcloud

We are having solr architecture as
[image]

We are facing the frequent replication failure between master to repeater server  as well as between repeater  to slave servers.On checking logs found every time one of the below  exceptions occurred whenever the replication have failed.

1)
[image]
2)
[image]

3)

[image]

The replication configuration of master,repeater,slave's is given below:
[image]

Commit Configuration master,repeater,slave's is given below :
[image]

Replication between master and repeater occurs every 10 mins.
Replication between repeater and slave servers occurs every 15 mins between 4-7 am and after that in every 3 hours.

Please help in replication failure issue.

Comment: "NoSuchFileException" seems to indicate that the file is being removed beneath the reading process (which would also explain the file disappearing while being transferred from your other question). Are the files on a local file system or are they on NFS or some other networked file system? Are there multiple Solr processes using the same `/data/solr/...` directory? Is the file system a permanent one, or a tmpfs/memory backed one? Are these exceptions on the master, the repeater or the slaves?

Comment: @MatsLindh Yes files are on local file system . /data/solr/.... is used by one solr only but we have multiple cores in this directory all of them having separate directory for index data. Yes the file system is permanent one. "NoSuchFileException on master only and on slave ,repeater all 3 exceptions are coming"

Comment: Could it be that commits happen very often? I.e. the `commitReserveDuration`? Could you try changing `replicateAfter` to just `startup` and see if the same issue still occurs? (you can also add `optimize` to make it more explicit - make sure you still have `commit` on your repeater). A guess could be that an index that's being replicate is removed beneath Solr because it's no longer necessary and the searches has been closed. Does the same issue occur for all cores, or just for one of them?

Comment: @MatsLindh the issue occur for all cores

Comment: No it fails on only 1 core. The size of core on which it's failing is 90 GB